# HashMap only printing out last value in JTable row

Tags: java

I really tried searching for the solution to this problem, but I cant seem to get it right. I have an application that Im working on, and I would like to print out all of a customers orders in a JTable with rows. So if a customer has three orders I want it to show each order on a separate row.

With this code (the next block) I got it to work, but it's only printing out the last value. So if I have Order 3 attached to a customer, and then add Order 4, it only shows Order 4.

```
JButton btnHämtaKund = new JButton("Hämta");
    btnHämtaKund.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            String searchTerm = sökrutaKund.getText();
            Customer c = Controller.findCustomer(searchTerm);
            String sum = "";
            if (c != null) {
                if (c.getOrders() != null) {
                    for (Order tmp : c.getOrders().values()) {
                        String date = tmp.getDate();
                        String price = Double.toString(tmp.getPrice());
                        String rfd = "";
                        if (tmp.getRdyForDelivery() == true) {
                            rfd = "Ready for delivery";
                        } else if (tmp.getRdyForDelivery() == false) {
                            rfd = "Processing";
                        }
                        model.addRow(new String[] {date, price, rfd});
                    }
                    txtfieldTestKund.setText(sum);
                } else {
                    txtfieldTestKund.setText("c.getOrders() == null");
                }
            } else {
                txtfieldTestKund.setText("c == null");
            }
        }
    });
```

Model is my DefaultModelTable.

I also tried with a for-loop like this in case I was overwriting my last row all the time:

```
                    for (int i = 0; i < c.getOrders().size(); i++) {
                        String date = c.getOrders().get(i).getDate();
                        String price = Double.toString(c.getOrders().get(i).getPrice());
                        String rfd = "";
                        if (c.getOrders().get(i).getRdyForDelivery() == true) {
                            rfd = "Ready for delivery";
                        } else if (c.getOrders().get(i).getRdyForDelivery() == false) {
                            rfd = "Processing";
                        }
                        Object row[] = {date, price, rfd};
                        model.addRow(row);
                      }
```

but that just gave a Nullpointerexception.
Any ideas what to do? Really thankful for help!

Comment: which row throws NullPointerException? Can you include the stacktrace?

Comment: The nullpointer is thrown at   String date = c.getOrders().get(i).getDate(); and if I remove that, it's thrown on the next line, which is     String price = Double.toString(c.getOrders().get(i).getPrice()); @XiaweiZhang

Comment: hmmm if I am not wrong getOrders() returns HashMap, and you are having index as the key of the HashMap?

Comment: @XiaweiZhang Yes correct

Comment: Baltzar, can you add the "solved" part as an answer and accept it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to fix a method to increase the key for each Order i added to Customer, looks like I was overwriting the previous with the last one.

```
private int counter = 0;
public void add(Order o) {
   counter += 1;
   String newCounter = Integer.toString(counter);
   this.orders.put(newCounter, o);
}
```